# Sql server doesn't have access to VirtualBox shared folder

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server

I am trying to configure Log Shipping in SQL Server between two VirtualBox machines. On both machines `SQL Server 2008 R2` has been installed. The OS of the machines is `Windows Server 2008R2`.

I have created a shared folder using `Devices -> Shared Folders...` and have given full access to it. The shared folder is created with `Auto-mount` and `Permanent` options.

The following screenshot depicts the shared folder on the first guest machine.

[image]

Unfortunately SQL Server seems to completely ignore the presence of this folder. I cannot restore a `*.bak` file stored into the folder, neither can I specify the folder as a back up shared for the Log Shipping operation.

Does any one have any idea how can I get around this problem?

Comment: Can you see it from just explorer ? Have you tried to mount through NET command ? Maybe the routing is not working properly? Maybe if it is a ONETIME job why do you not set up a simple WEB server of FTP on the Virtual Machine and just download it :) Please explain more indetails

Comment: And if possible please also Tell us the Networking setup for the VM, show Server IPCONFIG and Virtual machine IPCONFIG

Comment: @dExIT I can see the share from explorer. I can copy files from it as well copy files to the share. The problem is the SQL Server cannot access the share. It is invisible to the sql server instance.

Comment: @dExIT I also can connect to the sql server instance of the second machine from SSMS of the first machine and vice versa.

Comment: Gave my answer but will update as you check and will try to solve this :P

Comment: Did you try to access this folder from query? Something like `USE [master]
RESTORE DATABASE DB
FROM  DISK = N'\\vboxsrv\Backups\DB.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,  
GO`

Comment: Then the question about networking comes to mind, because you have not provided IP information, so we cannot know if the VM1 sees VM2

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mentioned are you able to ping your server or not, if you are not able to ping please check your network connectivity and check client machine is able to ping or not, if you get response from server then try now.

Network Configuration for Virtual Machine is here (for VMWare)
Go in 
setting >> Network Adapter >> Network Connection >> Bridge: Direct Connection to the Physical Network and check Replicate Physical network connection state.

Answer (score 0):

Solution #1

**You did not mention that you set up shared folder in VirtualBox, so:**

On your running VM instance

- `@ VirtualBox software menu bar -> Devices -> Shared Folders`

**Note** : It is highly recommended that you install Guest Addition to improve your guess OS performance and capability

- `Click on [+] button, in the new popup window on the right side`
- `Add the folder that you wanna share from your host OS (PC) @ ‘Folder Path’ -> Chose Other`
- `Choose your shared folder (this folder exist on your hosts VirtualDisks OS)`
- `The Click OK.`
- `Then name your shared folder name in the field "Folder Name :".`

Now it should look like:

```
"Folder Path:[G:\VirtualDisk\...\...\Share]"

"Folder Name:[Shared]"
```

- `Now on your Host machine open CMD (Admin) -> type:
  net use X: \\vboxsvr\Shared`

Close SQL and re-launch, and try again

Ideas: http://helpdeskgeek.com/virtualization/virtualbox-share-folder-host-guest/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've already installed Guest Addition. I  don't want to share the folder between the Guest and the Host. I want to share it between the two guests.

Comment: Can you please check the edit I made?

Comment: Then the question about networking comes to mind, because you have not provided IP information, so we cannot know if the VM1 sees VM2

Comment: It does see it because I can connect to the SQL Server instance of the second machine from SSMS running on the first machine and vice versa

Comment: Please provide in your answer, with screenshots on settings for both VMs NATs and what have you configured ? Without that there is no way for anyone to replicate the issue

Comment: The problem I'm facing is not a communication issue between the two guests. It is concerned with the communication between SQL Server and the shared folder within each VM. I can use Notepad inside a VM to save a file to the shared folder. I cannot use SQL Server to save a log file in a Log Shipping configuration.